# Turn off Celery task delay on development server

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm using Celery on Heroku with RabbitMQ and the following settings:

```
# settings.py

DEFAULT_AMQP = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost//"
BROKER_URL = os.getenv('CLOUDAMQP_URL', DEFAULT_AMQP)
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_STORE_ERRORS_EVEN_IF_IGNORED = True
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = False
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 5

# trying to clean up this memory leak
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 5
CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 60*10  # time limit in seconds--watch if we end up throwing big tasks onto this
```

I generally call tasks using `.delay()`.

On Heroku, I'd have to provision a separate worker dyno to handle these queued processes.  For the development server, I'd like to still call my delayed tasks, but do it in the same thread rather than defer it to a worker queue.  This means that every time I call `.delay()`, on the staging server, I want not to delay the task but actually just to call it as if I had used the normal `.__call__()` method.

Is there a Celery setting or some other way that I can basically turn Celery off and have calls to `.delay()` pass to `.__call__()` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER to True for the dev env: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-always-eager

Comment: the url is unfortunately 404; also, the setting has been renamed to CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44319939/426790